# lower function inside replace() in Oracle SQL Problem

Tags: sql, database, oracle, replace, lowercase

I am searching for a pattern "hello world" and replaced with Hello Bob.

Here I want to match all patterns of hello world. The problem is that we cannot match both patterns in replace function. so I make it lower and replacing.

As a Result , It making the whole string as lowercase.
"this is  Hello Bob program!. this is Hello Bob program"

But I want it as "**T**his is  Hello Bob **P**rogram!. **T**his is Hello Bob **P**rogram"

This is the query:
`select replace(lower('This is  Hello World Program!. This is hello world Program'),lower('Hello world'),'Hello Bob') from dual;`

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are receiving your result in all lower case because you are performing the `LOWER` function on your source string. Instead of using `REPLACE`, you can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490) since that function has the ability to ignore case sensitivity.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('This is  Hello World Program!. This is hello world Program',
                       'Hello world',
                       'Hello Bob',
                       1,
                       0,
                       'i')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Can you pls explain, why 1 and 0 are passing there

Comment: Why wouldn't you, @Yash, read documentation EJ posted? It explains *everything*.

Comment: @Yash - those are the default values for the `position` and `occurrence` arguments, as shown in the documentation EJ linked to; as they are defaults they can usually be omitted, but as these are positional parameters you have to supply values for those in order to be able to supply a value for the `match_param` argument.

Comment: If you click on the link I had provided, it has the documentation for each of the parameters. 1 is the position of the string to start searching and the 0 is which occurrence to replace. 0 means all occurrences.

Comment: Apologize I missed that.. Thank you all for your responses. I got that. Once again Thank you so much for your time to helping me